# how to fill format (a_content_type) while creating a document in DFS?

Tags: documentum

I am developing a DFS application (оn С#) that imports a document into Documentum as dm_document. A document may be in any format – DOC, DOC, PDF, whatever. Thus, when I create a document, I have to specify corresponding format (it will be put into a_content_type): “gif”, “msw8” etc.

How can I solve this task? I have looked through DFS_66_reference.pdf and DFS-SDK Help – do not see simple solution yet. Can you give me an advice?

Answer (score 3):

I usually do what David suggests for common formats that I am expecting to encounter.  This has the added benefit of giving you a reference to look at while debugging your application.  For other formats, you can make the following query.

DQL:

```
SELECT name from dm_format WHERE dos_extension = lower('<extension>')
```

Note that this is not always reliable, because it could return multiple results for an extension (XLS is a good example), so you should decide how to handle multiple results.  You may have to ask the user in that case.

I would recommend caching the responses in your application so you are not making this query needlessly.  As David said above, these values do not change unless you change them.

Comment: Thank you.In addition I could tell: in principle it is possible to use a software that reads a file and RECOGNIZES its format by its content. Example of such software is Oracle Outside In component - it recognizes HUNDREDS of formats. But this solution is, of course, expensive one

Comment: @KellyLynch yes, you could try to use another tool/library to determine the type as well (using MIME or other headers).

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to match the dos extension to Documentum format ?

If yes, the simplest is to simply hardcode the mapping directly in your application.

In Webtop file wdk/app.xml there is the mapping it uses.

Here is what I have in mine :

> ```
>               <format extension="txt" name="crtext"/>
>               <format extension="xls" name="excel8book"/>
>               <format extension="doc" name="msw8"/>
>               <format extension="ppt" name="ppt8"/>
>               <format extension="vsd" name="vsd"/>
>               <format extension="zip" name="zip"/>
>               <format extension="wpd" name="wp8"/>
>               <format extension="psd" name="photoshop6"/>
>               <format extension="au" name="audio"/>
>               <format extension="jpeg" name="jpeg"/>
>               <format extension="jpg" name="jpeg"/>
>               <format extension="html" name="html"/>
>               <format extension="htm" name="html"/>
>               <format extension="ai" name="illustrator10"/>
> ```

Comment: Well, my question was broader - I would like to know a best solution for the problem: how to specify corresponding format when my software [automatically, without possibility to ask a user] imports lot of documents into Documentum.  Yes, I have understood your answer - this is what I need.

Comment: I don't see where I am suggesting asking the user. And for a more generic solution, you can read dm_format objects in the docbase... But I don't really see the point, these objects almost never change. An hardcoded mapping is just simpler.