# How to determine the file type when a document is pulled from documentum

Tags: wdk, documentum, dfc

Which attribute can be used to pass the File Name while ingesting a document?

How to determine the file type when a document is pulled from Documentum using DFC API

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Once a file is uploaded to Documentum, it "loses" its filename. A document is linked to a content object, which is again linked to the file itself on a filestore.

There are ways to get hints about the original filename and/or file extensions:

1. Find the Content ID by looking at `i_contents_id`, and look at *that* object's `set_file` attribute. Normally, this string will contain the full path to path (including filename) of the original file, but there are no guarantees.
2. If storage extensions are *on* (yes, they're on by default), you could use the following API command to get the file extension: `getpath,c,<doc_id>`
3. The document's `a_content_type` links to the `name` attribute of a `dm_format` object. Look at that object's `dos_extension` attribute to see the registered file extension for that given format (there is no guarantee that this was the original file extension, however).

As for which attribute should contain the filename, there is no clear answer. It's all up to the client. Normally, using `object_name`should suffice, or you could create a custom type with a custom attribute if the original filename is very important to you.

Comment: can you Please proivde the DFC API calls?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no equivalent of `getpath` in DFC. I would code my way around it. But why do you need it, anyway? Normally this should only be necessary for very technical debugging etc., not in programs and/or more regular use cases.

Answer (score 0):

File in Documentum repository don't need to have document names that is originating from file that was uploaded from file system. 
When you export document via export action with WDK application, i.e. Documentum Administrator or Webtop exported file will have name based on the value that was place in `object_name` property of that specific object.

File type of the content that is related to sepecific document object in repository is written in attribute `a_content_type`. Values in this attribute are internal Documetnum notation but names are intuitive. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535446/how-to-fill-format-a-content-type-while-creating-a-document-in-dfs) for more info or google.